# SSAS Multidimensional - Access specific fact on specific dimensionnal

Tags: ssas, user-roles, multidimensional-cube

Context:

1 role authorize all facts data with a filter in Dimension Data on a society

Need:

Some members in the first role need access to some facts (but not authorize on all facts) in other society

I create a second role with dimension data filter on other societies and cell data Enable read permissions with this code :"Measures.CurrentMember IS [Measures].[QUANTITE STOCK]"

Problem:
Members in this second role AND in the first role can see all facts for all society.

For example, i want they can see [Measures].[CA HT N] only for the society in the first role but I want they can see [Measures].[QUANTITE STOCK] for all societies in the two roles.

Comment: Show the code of what you have tried.

Comment: I put this code on "Cell Data" -> "Allow reading of cube content": code`(Measures.CurrentMember IS [Measures].[QUANTITE STOCK]) and ([MAGASIN].[MAGASIN].&[1.5E1] is [Measures].[CA HT N]). This code is on the Role 2 but no code on Role 1

Comment: I have seen that ROle are additive. So, I need to create only one role where user can see [Measures].[QUANTITE STOCK] for all Societies in dimension MAGASIN and user can see [Measures].[CA HT N] only for [MAGASIN].[MAGASIN].&[1.5E1].  But i don't know how to do that